# Django- distinct doesn't work on order by

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have 2 models as follows:

```
class Chat(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class ChatMessage(models.Model):
    chat = models.ForeingKey(Chat, related_name="messages")
    text = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I want to get all chats order by last message created datetime.
Some chats may not have messages, so I want to be at the end of the list.

I tested following ways:
1- `chats = Chat.objects.all().order_by(F('messages__created').desc(nulls_last=True)).distinct()`
2- `chats = Chat.objects.all().order_by('-messages__created').distinct()`
3- `chats = Chat.objects.all().annotate(last_message=Max("messages__created").order_by("-last_message")`

ways 1 and 2 return duplicate values. 
way 3 return non-duplicate date but chats with no message are on the top of the list. I want to be at the end of the list.

**EDIT:**
I use Postgresql as database.

Comment: For me, using sqlite, 3 returns the correct result, what DB are you using?

Comment: @IainShelvington I'm using Postgresql. Thanks. I will edit the post.

Comment: Postgresql I suppose, nulls first is default for descending order and it is possible to set it in Django as in answer below

Comment: @iklinac Yes, The answer has been written by me :D. I'm searching for better approach if exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following works:

```
chats = Chat.objects.all().annotate(
    last_message=Max("messages__created")
).order_by(
    F("last_message").desc(nulls_last=True)
)
```

This works as I want (order by 'messages__created' and with no duplicates).

But I don't know how is good in case of performance.
Anyone has better approach instead of my way?